# SQL Server Incorrect syntax near

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following T-SQL code that run in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
DECLARE JF_PF CURSOR FOR

SELECT a.Region, ..... (shorten for display) ;  

OPEN JF_PF;

FETCH NEXT FROM JF_PF 
INTO @varRegion, @varLocationId, @varTransDate, @varcontractTypeName, @varOriginalPrepaidDues, @varNewPrepaidDues, @varJoiningFee, @varPrepaidFeePackage;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    IF @varcontractTypeName = 'New Join' and @varNewPrepaidDues = 'Dues'
          @varNewJoin_Dues_JF = @varJoiningFee;
    IF @varcontractTypeName = 'New Join' and @varNewPrepaidDues = 'Prepaid'
          BEGIN
                @varNewJoin_Prepaid_JF = @varJoiningFee;
                @varNewJoin_Prepaid_PF = @varPrepaidFeePackage;
          END;
    IF @varcontractTypeName = 'Renew' and @varOriginalPrepaidDues = 'Prepaid' and @varNewPrepaidDues = 'Prepaid'
          BEGIN
                @varRenew_PrepaidPrepaid_JF = @varJoiningFee;
                @varRenew_PrepaidPrepaid_PF = @varPrepaidFeePackage;
          END;
    IF @varcontractTypeName = 'Upgrade' and @varOriginalPrepaidDues = 'Dues' and @varNewPrepaidDues = 'Prepaid'
          BEGIN
                @varUpgrade_DuesPrepaid_JF = @varJoiningFee;
                @varUpgrade_DuesPrepaid_PF = @varPrepaidFeePackage;
          END;
    IF @varcontractTypeName = 'Upgrade' and @varOriginalPrepaidDues = 'Prepaid' and @varNewPrepaidDues = 'Prepaid'
          @varUpgrade_PrepaidPrepaid_PF = @varPrepaidFeePackage;

    FETCH NEXT FROM JF_PF 
    INTO @varRegion, @varLocationId, @varTransDate, @varcontractTypeName, @varOriginalPrepaidDues, @varNewPrepaidDues, @varJoiningFee, @varPrepaidFeePackage;
END;

CLOSE JF_PF ;  
DEALLOCATE JF_PF ;
```

When it is executed, I got the following message inside the cursor while loop.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 105
>   Incorrect syntax near '@varNewJoin_Dues_JF'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 108
>   Incorrect syntax near '@varNewJoin_Prepaid_JF'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 113
>   Incorrect syntax near '@varRenew_PrepaidPrepaid_JF'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 118
>   Incorrect syntax near '@varUpgrade_DuesPrepaid_JF'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 122
>   Incorrect syntax near '@varUpgrade_PrepaidPrepaid_PF'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 126
>   Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong for the syntax? Thanks.

Jimmy

Comment: Obviously those variables are all declared before.

Comment: You are missing the keyword `SET`. Put it before the assignments (e.g. before `@varNewJoin_Dues_JF = @varJoiningFee;`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you need to use `set` or `select` to set variables.  So:

```
set @varNewJoin_Prepaid_JF = @varJoiningFee;
set @varNewJoin_Prepaid_PF = @varPrepaidFeePackage;
```

Or, combine them into one statement using `select`:

```
select @varNewJoin_Prepaid_JF = @varJoiningFee,
       @varNewJoin_Prepaid_PF = @varPrepaidFeePackage;
```

Your particular code isn't doing anything other than setting variables.  I wonder if you could eliminate the cursor from your code entirely.

Comment: I have to assign on different variable according to different value of table data, any suggestion?